# Javascript to replace number's decimals

Tags: javascript

I have a list of numbers that goes by percentage like this:

```
 100.0%
 84.0%
 100.0%
 90.0%
 73.0%
```

and so on...

There is not a decimal like: 73.4%, only integers.

I'm looking for a javascript code that converts those numbers to decimals such as:

```
 10.0
 8.4
 10.0
 9.0
 7.3
```

And removing the % symbol. How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much for your time,

Comment: Divide your number by 10?

Comment: `parseFloat('100.0%') / 10`

Comment: thats the answer, nice one @JamieBarker

Answer (score 1):

With parseFloat and a division by 10:

```js
document.write(parseFloat('100.0%') / 10);
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. May I ask you how could I make it work on a list that is already generated in a table like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wxn1e6L1/

Comment: i suggest to make changes before the table is generated.

Answer (score 1):

what about `(parseFloat('100.0%') / 10).toFixed(1)`

Example:

```js
document.write((parseFloat('100.0%') / 10).toFixed(1))
```

Comment: Thanks, could I ask you how could I make parseFloat() work on a list that is already generated in a table like this? jsfiddle.net/wxn1e6L1

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to parse number. Then divide by 10 and use `.toFixed(1)` to fix decimal place to 1

```js
var perc = ['100.0%',
 '84.0%',
 '100.0%',
 '90.0%',
 '73.0%'];

for(i=0;i<perc.length;i++) {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += (parseInt(perc[i])/10).toFixed(1) + ', ';
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you how could I make it work on a list that is already generated in a table like this? jsfiddle.net/wxn1e6L1

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way...

```
var test = '73.0%';
var subst = test.substring(0, test.length - 1);
var value = parseFloat(subst) / 10;
console.log(value);
```

You're simply dropping the % symbol and then parsing the string as a floating point number, and dividing it by 10.

Comment: Hi @ManoDestra, thank you!. May I ask you how could I make it work on a list that is already generated in a table like this? jsfiddle.net/wxn1e6L1

Comment: Do you have it in an array in your Javascript, or do you have to parse the DOM? I'm hoping it's not the latter. That would be wrong. You should use this method here to format that data prior to being placed in the HTML. Or simply do it server side and present the correct response in the first place.

In other words, what data structure is your original % strings in?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the later. This is a mere styling issue; I'm trying to print that table, with the corrected values. I was thinking of replace()

Comment: How does that table get generated in the first place though? It must come from some kind of data, either server side scripting or from Javascript. You're surely not trying to parse through static HTML in the DOM and change the values via Javascript? Don't do that, whatever you do.